# jQuery UI Tabs check return data and and its type

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI 1.10.1 tabs with jQuery 1.9.1.
I load content via Ajax, it works fine. until users session expire and server return json response with URL to redirect to login page. but i can't check that return data type or return data. 
I already tested load event and its objects UI and Panel parameters don't give any information what kind of data is returned from server.

when I change server response type to 302 header with path to login page it does not redirect to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution create a hook for [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) and that give access to XHR status. so if server send back 302 header we can check it and do redirect. it still does not five access to returned data type.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, XHR, settings, exception) {
$('.ajaxDiv').hide();
if (XHR.status == 200) {

} else if (XHR.status == 500) {
    alert('500 Internal Server Error please retry');
} else if (XHR.status == 404) {
    alert('404 Not Found');
} else if (XHR.status == 403 || XHR.status == '403 Forbidden') {
    window.location.href = '/user/login';
} else if (XHR.status == 302) {
    window.location.href = XHR.responseText;
}
});
```